# How to display JavaScript function via HTML button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

I want to display the smallest entered number using HTML button. HTML form gets 3 numbers from user and using JavaScript it displays the smallest number on button click.

```
<form id="3nr">
  <p><input type="number" placeholder="Numri i pare..."></p>
  <p><input type="number" placeholder="Numri i dyte..."></p>
  <p><input type="number" placeholder="Numri i trete..."></p>
  <p>Numri me i vogel = <output name="min"></output></p>

</form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
    const form = document.querySelector('form')
const inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]')
const out = document.querySelector('output')

form.addEventListener('input', e => {
  out.value = Math.min(...Array.prototype.map.call(inputs, input => input.value))
}, false)
        </script>
```

Comment: So what's the actual problem with the code you've got? Are errors reported? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: Your question is actually a statement

Comment: The code works good but it displays the smallest number automatically while i want to display it with a button...

Comment: you are attaching a `input` event listener. Add a button and attach a click event listener which does the same job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a button to your form and attach an event-listener for the `click` event to it.

```js
const action = document.getElementById('action');
const form = document.querySelector('form')
const inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
const out = document.querySelector('output');

action.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault(); // do not submit the form on click of our button
  out.value = Math.min(...Array.prototype.map.call(inputs, input => input.value))
}, false)
```

```html
<form id="3nr">
  <p><input type="number" placeholder="Numri i pare..."></p>
  <p><input type="number" placeholder="Numri i dyte..."></p>
  <p><input type="number" placeholder="Numri i trete..."></p>
  <p><button id="action">Display</button></p>
  <p>Numri me i vogel = <output name="min"></output></p>
</form>
```